# How to scrapp a embedded pdf in dynamic website using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pdf

I'm trying to download a lot of pdf's (This is publically available degree works) from a list of URLs (for example, I'm trying to make work: https://opac.crzp.sk/?fn=detailBiblioFormChildAI98J&sid=C7058B2E53B5EC4D981562B8211A&seo=CRZP-detail-kniha) I'm using Selenium to accomplish my task, however, I can't download nothing and I can't figure out what's the problem, since there is no error. I would appreciate any suggestions or possible solutions. Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests
import os

urls = [
    "https://opac.crzp.sk/?fn=detailBiblioForm&sid=72C84F3CCF0D479C0581025BBB18"
   ]

# Function to download PDFs
def download_pdfs(urls):
    download_folder = "D:\\Web_Scrapper_Project\\docs"    
    
    profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False,
                                         "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
               "download.default_directory": download_folder,
               "download.extensions_to_open": "",
               "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
    options = Options()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')  # Ignore SSL certificate errors
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) #Solving AIA error
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    
    for url in urls:
        driver.get(url)
        try:
            # Updated to specifically target the element structure provided
            download_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[i[@title="Stiahnuť prácu (pdf)"]]')))
            download_button.click()

            # Retrieve the embedded PDF URL
            pdf_frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'object')))
            pdf_url = pdf_frame.get_attribute('data')

            if not os.path.exists('pdfs'):
                os.makedirs('pdfs')

            # Download the PDF
            response = requests.get(pdf_url)
            with open(f'{hash(response.content)}.pdf', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
            print(f"PDF downloaded from {url}")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to download PDF from {url}: {e}")

        #finally:
            #driver.quit()

download_pdfs(urls)
def main():
    download_pdfs(urls)
```

Output:
PS C:\Users\Craboteam11> & C:/Users/Craboteam11/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe d:/Web_Scrapper_Project/scrapper.py
PDF downloaded from https://opac.crzp.sk/?fn=detailBiblioForm&sid=72C84F3CCF0D479C0581025BBB18

It doesn't download anything anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for answer, 
But I'm waiting for modal window it to load, after clicking on <a>, and then I search for object that already loaded in this part of code, #Retrieve the embedded PDF URL. Please, if I am wrong let me know